# How does Haskell evaluate expression

Tags: haskell, expression

How come that this works

```
> (* 30) 4
120
```

but this doesn't

```
> * 30 40
error: parse error on input ‘*’
```

Comment: First one is equivalent to `(\x -> x * 30) 4`, second one is calling `*` as if it's non-infix operator but a function, which is not valid, `(*) 30 40` should be used instead.

Comment: You're asking how Haskell parses that code, not about evaluation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(* 30)` is a *section*, which still treats `*` as a binary (infix) operator, just one that's missing an argument, short for `(\x -> x * 30)`. The parentheses themselves are part of the syntax, rather than being the explicit (but redundant) parentheses you can wrap around an arbitrary expression.

You can think of `(*)` as a degenerate section that is missing *both* arguments. You cannot otherwise use an infix operator in the prefix position without using parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell uses a special syntax for partial application of infix operators (`*`, `+`, `^` etc). It will only work inside brackets from what I understand. https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator